# How to change word to be uppercase in string and keep the rest?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to change word to be uppercase in string?

for example I have this string: `\u001b[31merror\u001b[39m` and if the `error` word is exist then I want to make her uppercase, so the output should be: `\u001b[31mERROR\u001b[39m`.

Why when I use regex it will not work? `\u001b[31merror\u001b[39m.replace( /(error)/, "$1".toUpperCase())`

`error` can be any lowercase word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the `toUpperCase()` is applied at the string "$1" and then the result of that operation i passed as second argument of the `replace` method; you instead expect that `toUpperCase` is called with the `value` found. To do so, you need to pass a function as second argument of `replace`:

```
"\u001b[31merror\u001b[39m".replace(/(error)/, $1 => $1.toUpperCase())
```

That would work (notice, `$1` here is just  an arbitrary variable name, you can call it as you want).

However, since you said that `error` is just an example, you could either list all the possible values:

```
mystring.replace(/(error|info|warning)/, $1 => $1.toUpperCase())
```

Or just replace everything is between `\u001b[31m` and `\u001b[39m` (assuming they don't change):

```js
const mystring = `\u001b[31merror\u001b[39m`;
console.log(
  mystring.replace(/\u001b\[31m(.*)\u001b\[39m/, $1 => $1.toUpperCase())
);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: YES! Thanks for the explanation and solution!

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
'\u001b[31merror\u001b[39m'.replace(/(error)/, RegExp.$1.toUpperCase())
```

This will replace the string 'error' and change it to 'ERROR'

Comment: Thanks but the word can be anything like error, info … the error is just example

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: It is not replacing any lowercase word as is requested but ONLY error

Comment: @mplungjan The user has asked that he wants to replace a particular lowercase word. He will have to specify the word that he wants to replace as the string may contain more than one lowercase words.

Comment: _Thanks but the word can be anything like error, info … the error is just example_